# How to check if a file contains only zeros in a Linux shell?

Tags: linux, file, shell

How to check if a large file contains only zero bytes (`'\0'`)  in Linux using a shell command? I can write a small program for this but this seems to be an overkill.

Comment: Can it include newline characters?

Comment: @CodeBlue No, only zero bytes.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you're using bash, you can use `read -n 1` to exit early if a non-`NUL` character has been found:

```
<your_file tr -d '\0' | read -n 1 || echo "All zeroes."
```

where you substitute the actual filename for `your_file`.

Comment: It's worth noting that `file` is the filename here, not the command `file`.

Comment: I'd add: for people like me who don't know all bash syntax and don't like "cryptic" notations (this is of course subjective), this is equivalent to :
`cat you_file | tr -d '\0' | read -n 1 || echo "All zeroes."`

Comment: Also note, that you can drop the 'useless cat' by doing
```sh
tr -d '\0' < [your_file] | read -n 1 || echo "All zeroes."
```

Though I'd favor a more posix way by dropping the -n 1 and using `wc` instead,

Comment: And since I was to slow to edit, here would be my suggestion:


```if [ "$(tr -d '\0' < [your_file] | wc -c)" -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "All zeroes."
fi
```

where 'tr' deletes any character in the source file (`\0` in this case) and thus, the count should be 0.

And sorry for the formatting, but < code > nor ` ` ` seem to work today?

Answer (score 16):

The "file" `/dev/zero` returns a sequence of zero bytes on read, so a `cmp file /dev/zero` should give essentially what you want (reporting the first different byte just beyond the length of `file`).

Comment: Good answer. Actually one can tell `cmd` how many bytes to compare, so `cmp -n $(stat -c %s $FILE) $FILE /dev/zero` works like a charm.

Comment: this is better than the accepted answer from a not-reading-a-byte-at-a-time point of view. But if you're writing in bash, you probably don't care about that.

Comment: @stu, if your file is a few megabytes long, it sure makes a difference.

Comment: yeah, I was more thinking, if your file is megabytes long and you're going to be doing it a lot, you wouldn't be using a scripting language

Comment: @stu if you do it a few times, your time is much more valuable than the computer's

Comment: I spend a lot of the time the computer is doing something, doing something else, like sleeping. You can pay more for faster processors, or you can just schedule your time more wisely.

Comment: @stu why not? Compiled, bummed for efficiency code for repetitive, heavy lifting; scripting for flexibility/choreography.

Comment: depends on the goal. if I'm writing something important for production that I don't want to get a call at 3am about, I'm going to put in lots of error checking and logging and redundancy and retry logic. Certainly you can do that in bash, but I'd prefer to do it in a language that already has logging libraries. that's more the angle I was getting at. In a bash script, I run it to make it go, and I don't care if it's a bit slow. If it needs to go faster, it's likely a production problem.

Comment: I found this answer trying to check if a region of a file was all zeroes. Thanks for the help: `cmp --ignore-initial=$offset:0 --bytes=$size $file /dev/zero` appears to work just fine. Where `file` is the file I am checking, at an offset of `offset` bytes into the file, and the region is `size` bytes in length. The `:0` indicates not to skip initial bytes in `/dev/zero`.

Answer (score 9):

If you have Bash,

```
cmp file <(tr -dc '\000' <file)
```

If you don't have Bash, the following should be POSIX (but I guess there may be legacy versions of `cmp` which are not comfortable with reading standard input):

```
tr -dc '\000' <file | cmp - file
```

Perhaps more economically, assuming your `grep` can read arbitrary binary data,

```
tr -d '\000' <file | grep -q -m 1 ^ || echo All zeros
```

I suppose you could tweak the last example even further with a `dd` pipe to truncate any output from `tr` after one block of data (in case there are very long sequences without newlines), or even down to one byte.  Or maybe just force there to be newlines.

```
tr -d '\000' <file | tr -c '\000' '\n' | grep -q -m 1 ^ || echo All zeros
```

Answer (score 5):

It won't win a prize for elegance, but:

```
xxd -p file | grep -qEv '^(00)*$'
```

`xxd -p` prints a file in the following way:

```
23696e636c756465203c6572726e6f2e683e0a23696e636c756465203c73
7464696f2e683e0a23696e636c756465203c7374646c69622e683e0a2369
6e636c756465203c737472696e672e683e0a0a766f696420757361676528
63686172202a70726f676e616d65290a7b0a09667072696e746628737464
6572722c202255736167653a202573203c
```

So we grep to see if there is a line that is not made completely out of 0's, which means there is a char different to '\0' in the file. If not, the file is made completely out of zero-chars.

(The return code signals which one happened, I assumed you wanted it for a script. If not, tell me and I'll write something else)

EDIT: added -E for grouping and -q to discard output.

Comment: The grouping with parentheses requires `grep -E` at least for me (but is obviously easy enough to fix).

Comment: For some reason it worked for me without -E. I had it on and dropped it by accident. Edited to add it. Thanks!

Comment: It may not win a prize for elegance, but quite possibly one for speed.

Comment: Also, this one wins (slightly modified) if files with runs of zeroes need to be identified. E.g. as read by 'cpio' from failing media.

Answer (score 0):

Straightforward:

```
if [ -n $(tr -d '\0000' < file | head -c 1) ]; then
   echo a nonzero byte
fi
```

The `tr -d` removes all null bytes. If there are any left, the `if [ -n` sees a nonempty string.

Comment: This will fail if the output from the backticks overflows `ARG_MAX`.  See http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#backticks

Comment: True. I added | head -c 1.

Answer (score -3):

Completely changed my answer based on the reply [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20226279/perl-detect-from-command-line-if-file-has-only-a-specified-character)

Try

```
perl -0777ne'print /^\x00+$/ ? "yes" : "no"' file
```

Comment: How do I send the file contents to perl via command line in that case? I checked with empty file and it doesn't produce "yes".

Comment: Sorry, empty files are fine but a file with one non-zero byte will produce "yes".

Comment: Perl, like most every Unix file handling utility, can read a file without the help of `cat` (with `tr` perhaps being the one notable exception).  `perl -ne 'print if s/^0+$/yes/' file`

Comment: Edited script to include "+" instead of *

Comment: It will still print something if there are characers which are not zeros.

Comment: You are completely misunderstanding the OP. The question asks how to  check if a file consists entirely of null characters (ASCII `0x00`) while your solution looks for literal zeros (ASCII `0x30`). @tripleee already pointed this out in an [earlier comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20224822/how-to-check-if-a-file-contains-only-zeros-in-a-linux-shell/20225286#comment30161126_20225286) but you seem to have ignored that.

Comment: Oh, I completely missed that. :(  Edited the answer

Comment: Your new answer will read the entire file into memory, which is unattractive if the input file could be multiple gigabytes.