# Using grep to find and delete files that are filled with zeros

Tags: file, command-line, grep, nul

I tried recovering a disk image from an NTFS hard drive that is 50% unreadable. And I guess a side effect of that is a lot of the files recovered have the correct filename and type, and take up the same file size as the original file, however instead of containing any useful data, they are just filled with 00 00 00 00 etc. in the HEX editor. Since these files aren't of any use but still take up disk space, is there a way to automate finding and deleting them all?

Comment: Do an inverse binary search for zero byte. Don't delete if anything is found in the file. Look up the man pages for which flags to use.

Comment: Let @tripleee help you... https://stackoverflow.com/a/20225032/2836621

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a file contains only zeros in a Linux shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20224822/how-to-check-if-a-file-contains-only-zeros-in-a-linux-shell)

Comment: I'm looking through old backups and also seeing ~50 GB files inside System Volume Information that have nothing but zeros when viewed in a hex editor.  Easy to delete those!

Answer (score 1):

After some research, I came up with

```
grep --ignore-case -r -L --null [^0] * | xargs -0 rm
```

Comment: This removes files which contain ony 0x30 bytes (the ASCII code for the character `0`). Some variants of `grep` might support the notation `[^\000]` or if you have Bash you can say `$'[^\x00]'`

Answer (score 0):

I tested [^0] and [^\000]
cases on:
1000B
2000B
3000B
...
5000000B
lenght zero-filled files.

Looks like both works properly.

Answer (score 0):

Finding files using https://stackoverflow.com/a/20226139/969504 answer:

```
find 2>/dev/null -type f -size +0c -exec bash -c '<"$0" tr -d "\0" | read -n 1 || echo "$0"' {} ';'
```